# String to Int with a + sign

Tags: java, parsing

I'm parsing stock data and trying to put it into a SQL database. All of the info from the parse is retrieved as a string. I am using the Integer.parseInt() method to try and convert the strings to integers for some of the info. The issue I am having is with the Change data. When it is a positive change the number has a "+" sign in front of it and I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+0.14" //
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) //
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) //
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) //
    at getStockData.main(getStockData.java:91)" (the //s are to signify end lines, having issues with formatting)
```

My Output is:

```
Ticker ID: MSFT: Change - [+0.14]

int Change = Integer.parseInt(di.getTextContent());
```

I don't really know how to get around this error at the moment, and haven't found anything similar to this after googling / searching stackoverflow.

Comment: Integers can't hold floating point values. Elliot Frisch's answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is `0.14` is not a valid `int`. Try using [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) to parse the `double` value. Like

```
double v = Double.parseDouble("+0.14");
System.out.println(v);
```

Output is

```
0.14
```